# How to create a summarize new row from a pandas Dataframe and add it back to the same Dataframe for only specific columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, pivot-table

I have the below pandas dataframe.

```
d = {'id1': ['85643', '85644','8564312','8564314','85645','8564316','85646','8564318','85647','85648','85649','85655'],'ID': ['G-00001', 'G-00001','G-00002','G-00002','G-00001','G-00002','G-00001','G-00002','G-00001','G-00001','G-00001','G-00001'],'col1': [1, 2,3,4,5,60,0,0,6,3,2,4],'Goal': [np.nan, 56,np.nan,89,73,np.nan ,np.nan ,np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 34,np.nan ], 'col2': [3, 4,32,43,55,610,0,0,16,23,72,48],'col3': [1, 22,33,44,55,60,1,5,6,3,2,4],'Name': ['aasd', 'aasd','aabsd','aabsd','aasd','aabsd','aasd','aabsd','aasd','aasd','aasd','aasd'],'Date': ['2021-06-13', '2021-06-13','2021-06-13','2021-06-14','2021-06-15','2021-06-15','2021-06-13','2021-06-16','2021-06-13','2021-06-13','2021-06-13','2021-06-16']}

dff = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
dff
     id1     ID     col1 Goal   col2    col3   Name      Date
0   85643   G-00001 1   NaN     3       1     aasd      2021-06-13
1   85644   G-00001 2   56.0000 4       22    aasd      2021-06-13
2   8564312 G-00002 3   NaN     32      33    aabsd     2021-06-13
3   8564314 G-00002 4   89.0000 43      44    aabsd     2021-06-14
4   85645   G-00001 5   73.0000 55      55    aasd      2021-06-15
5   8564316 G-00002 60  NaN     610     60    aabsd     2021-06-15
6   85646   G-00001 0   NaN     0       1     aasd      2021-06-13
7   8564318 G-00002 0   NaN     0       5     aabsd     2021-06-16
8   85647   G-00001 6   NaN     16      6     aasd      2021-06-13
9   85648   G-00001 3   NaN     23      3     aasd      2021-06-13
10  85649   G-00001 2   34.0000 72      2     aasd      2021-06-13
11  85655   G-00001 4   NaN     48      4     aasd      2021-06-16
```

I want to summarize some of the columns and add them back to the same datframe based on some ids in the "id1" column. Also, I want to give a new name to the "ID" column when we add that row.
for example, I have some "id1" column slices.

```
#Based on below "id1" column ids I want to summarize only "col1","col2","col3",and "Name" columns. #Then I want to add that row back to the same dataframe and give a new id for "ID" column. 
b65 = ['85643','85645', '85655','85646']
b66 = ['85643','85645','85647','85648','85649','85644']
b67 = ['8564312','8564314','8564316','8564318']
# I want to aggregate sum for col1,col2 and If possible col3 with average. Otherwise it also with sum.
# So final dataframe look like below
     id1     ID     col1 Goal   col2    col3   Name      Date
0   85643   G-00001 1   NaN     3       1     aasd      2021-06-13
1   85644   G-00001 2   56.0000 4       22    aasd      2021-06-13
2   8564312 G-00002 3   NaN     32      33    aabsd     2021-06-13
3   8564314 G-00002 4   89.0000 43      44    aabsd     2021-06-14
4   85645   G-00001 5   73.0000 55      55    aasd      2021-06-15
5   8564316 G-00002 60  NaN     610     60    aabsd     2021-06-15
6   85646   G-00001 0   NaN     0       1     aasd      2021-06-13
7   8564318 G-00002 0   NaN     0       5     aabsd     2021-06-16
8   85647   G-00001 6   NaN     16      6     aasd      2021-06-13
9   85648   G-00001 3   NaN     23      3     aasd      2021-06-13
10  85649   G-00001 2   34.0000 72      2     aasd      2021-06-13
11  85655   G-00001 4   NaN     48      4     aasd      2021-06-16
12          b65     10          106     61    aasd
13          b66     17          169     67    aasd
14          b67     67          685     142   aabsd   

#I was tried to do it in groupby and pandas pivot table and didn't get to work. Any suggestion would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!
```

Comment: How do you want to aggregate the name column?

Comment: sum for col1,col2,. If possible col3 with average. Otherwise it also with sum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure how you want to handle the name column but you could just add it to the agg function

```
b65 = ['85643','85645', '85655','85646']
b66 = ['85643','85645','85647','85648','85649','85644']
b67 = ['8564312','8564314','8564316','8564318']

# create a dictionary
d_map = {'b65': b65, 'b66': b66, 'b67': b67}
# dictionary comprehension
df = pd.DataFrame({k: dff[dff['id1'].isin(v)].agg({'col1': sum, 'col2': sum,
                                               'col3': 'mean', 'Name': min})
                   for k,v in d_map.items()}).T.reset_index()
# rename the columns
df = df.rename(columns={'index': 'ID'})
# concat the two frames
pd.concat([dff, df]).reset_index(drop=True)

        id1       ID col1  Goal col2       col3   Name        Date
0     85643  G-00001    1   NaN    3          1   aasd  2021-06-13
1     85644  G-00001    2  56.0    4         22   aasd  2021-06-13
2   8564312  G-00002    3   NaN   32         33  aabsd  2021-06-13
3   8564314  G-00002    4  89.0   43         44  aabsd  2021-06-14
4     85645  G-00001    5  73.0   55         55   aasd  2021-06-15
5   8564316  G-00002   60   NaN  610         60  aabsd  2021-06-15
6     85646  G-00001    0   NaN    0          1   aasd  2021-06-13
7   8564318  G-00002    0   NaN    0          5  aabsd  2021-06-16
8     85647  G-00001    6   NaN   16          6   aasd  2021-06-13
9     85648  G-00001    3   NaN   23          3   aasd  2021-06-13
10    85649  G-00001    2  34.0   72          2   aasd  2021-06-13
11    85655  G-00001    4   NaN   48          4   aasd  2021-06-16
12      NaN      b65   10   NaN  106      15.25   aasd         NaN
13      NaN      b66   19   NaN  173  14.833333   aasd         NaN
14      NaN      b67   67   NaN  685       35.5  aabsd         NaN
```

This is where the magic happens:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({k: dff[dff['id1'].isin(v)].agg({'col1': sum, 'col2': sum,
                                                   'col3': 'mean', 'Name': min})
                   for k,v in d_map.items()}).T.reset_index()
```

`dff[dff['id1'].isin(v)]` is called boolean indexing which filters your frame where `id1` is in `v` or the value for each key in the dict. The dictonary comprehension iterates through the `d_map` dictionary's key (k) and values (v)

`.agg` is a function used to aggregate data

Comment: Thanks, @It_is_Chris. So quick

Comment: Is it possible to fill the Name column too?. @it-is-chris

Comment: Yes, how to you want it filled? Is the name always the same for each group of b65, b66, b67? You can just do `.agg({'col1': sum, 'col2': sum, 'col3': 'mean', 'Name': 'unique'}` Unique will give you all the unique occurrences of`Name` for each group

Comment: Yes It's the same always

Comment: You are the best man! Thanks again!@it-is-chris

Comment: @rra since it is always the same it porbably makes more sense to use `min` rather than `unique` so you do not have to deal with the list: `.agg({'col1': sum, 'col2': sum, 'col3': 'mean', 'Name': min}`

Comment: @ It_is_Chris Sorry to bother you again. Do you know how to break it down list if we use "Unique" for the name column? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69802922/how-to-create-a-new-summarize-row-from-a-pandas-dataframe-base-on-two-columns

Answer (score 1):

you can do this:

```
all_lists = [b65,b66,b67]

for item in all_lists: 
    x = dff[dff.id1.isin(item)]
    y = x.sum()

    y.id1 = ''
    y.ID= ''
    y.Goal =''
    y.Name=''
    y.Date = ''

    dff = dff.append(y,ignore_index=True)
```

and this is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @sbabti-zied!